# Horizontally aligned fontawesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a unordered list where I have some font-awesome icons. I am trying to align them horizontally.  When I align them horizontally they stack up on each other a bit.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

CSS:

```
.tbl-op ul{margin-left: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;color:#2895f1;}.tbl-op li {cursor: pointer;display:inline-block;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group tbl-op" role="toolbar">
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-upload" title="Upload"></i>Upload</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-times"  title="Delete"></i>Delete</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-edit"  title="Edit"></i>Edit</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem found, live demo (with icons) http://jsfiddle.net/u0fL7rvx/

I don't know why font awesome add `position:absolute` to the icons. You can add the below rules to set it to `static`.

```
.tbl-op li .fa-li {
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

much simpler, change your markup to

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-upload" title="Upload"></i> Upload </li>
  <li class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-times"  title="Delete"></i> Delete</li>
  <li class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-edit"  title="Edit"></i> Edit </li>
</ul>
```

and just style the `li` tags

```
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/81rqm0h7/